Photo of Marcus Kann?
Does anyone know if this photo is in fact Marcus Kann?
Are there any better photographs that exist of him?


Perhaps you could add the reason for thinking that this might be a photo of Marcus Kann. Where did you get the photo from?

looks a bit like this guy https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q29535212#/media/File:Jean_Charles_de_Bouteiller_(1840-1885).jpg

this is where I got the photo from
http://www.bidmonfa.com/kann_marcus.htm
https://grandmastermac.com/the-caro-kann/

I should also add that I have looked in the Oxford Companion to chess the first edition, and though it obviously has the Caro Kann defence and mentions Marcus Kann, it does not have an entry for him. Apparently their recommendations for the defence appears in a German magazine "Bruderschaft" in 1886.
